Finding the sum of the floor function of $a,(b-1)/2,c$ given two symmetric sums
Problem: Let $a<b<c$ be $3$ real numbers satisfying $a+b+c=6$, $ab+bc+ca=9$. Then, determine the value of $\lfloor{a}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{b-1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor{c}\rfloor$.
My method of solution:
Suppose that $a,b,c$ are the roots of a cubic equation $x^3-6x^2+9x-abc=0$. Since $a,b,c$ are distinct and real, sketching a rough plot of the cubic, I noted that the maximum of this cubic must be positive and the minimum of the cubic must be negative for $3$ distinct roots to occur.
Applying these bounds, I got $0<abc<4$ (strict inequality because if the maximum or minimum is $0$, there will be a repeated root).
Next, I applied the intermediate value theorem on different intervals;
$f(0)=-abc<0$, $f(1)=4-abc>0 \implies a \in(0,1)$
$f(3)=-abc<0, f(4)=4-abc>0 \implies c \in(3,4)$
And finally, since $f(1)>0,f(3)<0, b\in(1,3)$
Hence, the answer to the problem is $3$.
However, I think I may have developed an overly complicated solution for this problem, and I'll be honest, the characteristic cubic equation idea took some time to motivate. So, I'm looking for a better shorter solution (applying the intermediate value theorem on the best intervals also took some time) which is a little easier to motivate. If someone can establish stronger bounds on $a,b,c$, that would also be much appreciated!
Edit: I'm not longer looking for an alternative solution because I don't think one is possible. However, I was playing around with this problem when I realised there's a non intuitive way of proving that only one among $a,b,c$ can be an integer. It relies on the fact that the floor of b can only attain the values ${1,2}$ so the sum of the fractional parts of $a,b,c$ can only be $1$ or $2$ i.e. at least two of the fractional parts must be nonzero. But if this problem were given directly to someone in the form that:
Problem: Let $a<b<c$ be $3$ real numbers satisfying $a+b+c=6$, $ab+bc+ca=9$. Prove that at most, only one among $a,b,c$ is an integer.
Then how would you solve it? (Please ignore the first question , this is the real question I mean to ask, the work done until now is just the prelude leading upto this.) This solution I invented here would be very difficult to motivate.

Have to say, that looks like an excellent approach to the problem.  Somehow, you need to argue that $a>0$  and  that's right on the edge, as $(0,3,3)$ satisfies everything except $b<c$.

I didn't notice that; actually, if I can argue $a>0$, then I can show that $abc<8$ by AM-GM

The first equality gives $a+b = 6-c$, and then the second gives
$\begin{align}
ab &= 9 - bc - ca \\
&= 9-(a+b)c \\
&= 9-(6-c)c \\
&= 9-6c+c^2.
\end{align}$
We know that $(a+b)^2 > 4ab$ (because $a \neq b$), and this is equivalent to $(6-c)^2 > 4 (9-6c+c^2)$, which simplifies as
$$0>3c(c-4)$$
from which we obtain $\boxed{0<c<4}$. Similarly, we have $\boxed{0<b<4}$ and $\boxed{0<a<4}$.
Now, it is easy to conclude that no more than one of $a,b,c$ can be an integer.
Notice that if more than one were integers, then all three have to be due to $a+b+c=6$ being an integer. However, due to $0<a,b,c<4$ and the given condition $a<b<c$, this would only be possible with $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$, but that does not satisfy $ab+ac+bc=9$ as it gives $11\neq9$.
As a result, $\boxed{\text{at most one of a,b,c can be an integer}}$.

Given $a<b<c$ with \begin{equation}\tag{$\ast$}a+b+c=6\quad \text{and}\quad ab+bc+ca=9,\end{equation} we want to prove that at most one of the variables can be an integer. Notice that as soon two of them are integral, so is the third because of the first equation. Hence it suffices to show that every integral solution of ($\ast$) has a repeated value.

Consider $$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=6^2-2\cdot9=18.$$ Since squares are non-negative, it's quite easy to check all options for this equation, and the only solutions are permutations of $$(\pm4,\pm1,\pm1)\quad\text{and}\quad(\pm3,\pm3,0).$$ To get the sum to $6$ one has to choose all signs positive in both cases, i.e. the only integral solutions to ($\ast$) are permutations of $(4,1,1)$ and $(3,3,0)$. But both of these have a repeated value, hence the original problem has no integral solution.


how would you solve it?

Suppose that two of $a,b,c$ are integers. Then, it follows from $a+b+c=6$ that $a,b,c$ are integers.
We have $abc\not=0$. (If $x+y=6$ and $xy=9$, then $x,y$ are the solutions of $t^2-6t+9=0$, i.e. $(t-3)^2=0$ which means $x=y=3$, a contradiction.)
We have
$$ab=9-c(a+b)=9-c(6-c)=(c-3)^2\ge 0$$
and
$$bc=9-a(b+c)=9-a(6-a)=(a-3)^2\ge 0$$
So, $a,b,c$ have to be positive.
Now, $6=a+b+c\gt a+a+a=3a$ implies $2\gt a\gt 0$, so we have to have $a=1,b+c=5$ and $bc=4$.
So, $b,c$ are the solutions of $t^2-5t+4=0$, i.e. $(t-1)(t-4)=0$. So, $(b,c)=(1,4)$ which contradicts $a\lt b$.
Therefore, we can say that at most, only one among $a,b,c$ is an integer.
